# Defining an atomic<> as a static variable inside a function

Tags: c++, c++11

C++11 mandates that static variables inside a function are atomically initialized for the first run of the function. The only way to do that efficiently is double-checked locking to prevent an expensive mutex-lock all the time.
I just had the necessity to have an static atomic<size_t> inside a function. It wouldn't make sense if such an atomic would be atomically initialized through double-checked locking. Instead it should be handled like another static initialized non-const native variable.
I checked the generated code with VC++ and Intel C++ under Windows and clang++ and g++ under Linux and all generated code according to my expectations. But is this really reliable and mandated by the standard that atomics should be handled independent of other objects here ?

Comment: The standard generally doesn't mandate any optimizations.

Comment: The standard mandates the behaviour not the implementation, a compiler can implement however it likes as long as the behaviour is correct, it could even just use a mutex directly

Comment: The standard partitially mandates optimizations, look at copy-elision.

Comment: What I'm saying is, the standard only describes how programs *behave*, not how stuff works under the hood. It doesn't mention "double-checked locking", or anything like that.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: Maybe, but thers's no other way to handle that efficiently differently.

Comment: The standard doesn't say anything about efficiency either. copy-elision isn't required because it is more efficient but because it changes the behavior. Compilers would not be allowed to copy-elide on their own because then code from different compilers would behave differently. They are also not allowed to no copy-elide because again that would create different behavior.

Comment: Ok, you're right, basic performance-concerns are always irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

The default constructor of `std::atomic` is **constexpr**, although until C++20 that's because it's trivial and the object can't yet be used.  That means that no dynamic initialization is required, which is as close as the standard gets to saying that this is efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Davis Herring is mostly right, it's because the datatype is a trivial datatype and the compiler can inspect its initialization to not have any side-effects (constexpr construction actually isn't necessary). I checked that with the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct S
{
    S( int i ) : i( i ) {}
    operator int() { return i; }
    ~S() {}
private:
    int i;
};

S &f();

int main()
{
    cout << f() << endl;
}

#if defined(_MSC_VER)
__declspec(noinline)
#elif defined(__llvm__) || defined(__GNUC__)
__attribute((noinline))
#endif
S &f()
{
    static S s( 123 );
    return s;
}
```

The above code generates the usual double-checked locking initialization. If you comment out the destructor of S the code in f() just returns a reference to statically initialized data in modifiable memory.